# Turning off AutoDeriveTypeable

Tags: haskell, ghc, rtti

Recent versions of GHC automatically derive `Typeable` instances for all data types. I would like to turn that off. Previously, the `AutoDeriveTypeable` language extension was used to enable this, so I thought if I use the `NoAutoDeriveTypeable` language pragma, that would do the trick. However, even though GHC emits no errors about unknown language pragmas, there seems to be no effect from `NoAutoDeriveTypeable`, since I can see the `Typeable`-related CAFs in the generated Core.

Comment: This observation might be better suited as a GHC issue. You can open one [here](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/new). I guess the remaining question is: "Is it possible to define a data type that doesn't have a Typeable instance?".

Comment: What reason did you have for wanting to do this?  Was it just code size or compilation speed, or is there a situation where a derived `Typeable` instance actually changes program semantics somehow?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I wanted code with no external dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a `DynFlag` for this](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/3d5cb3352c1e1c20f0d5de427f4edbc765ce06d6/compiler/GHC/Driver/Flags.hs#L155), and turns out [it can be turned on with the `-dno-typeable-binds` compile-time flag](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/debugging.html#ghc-flag--dno-typeable-binds). According to the docs, this flag is for debugging purposes only:

> **`-dno-typeable-binds`**
>
> This avoid generating `Typeable`-related bindings for modules and types. This is useful when debugging because it gives
> smaller modules and dumps, but the compiler will panic if you try to
> use `Typeable` instances of things that you built with this flag.